# Google script code formatted,colored and beautiful indent

Tags: formatting, google-docs, google-apps-script-editor

I wrote a container-bound script and now want to make a report from it, by inserting the code into a Google Docs file. The problem is that with copy & paste from the Script Editor, the code is no longer colored or indented. I will need your help because I don't know how to make it well done.
I have this code :

```js
createAndSendDocument() { 
  // Create a new Google Doc named 'Hello, world!' 
  var doc = DocumentApp.create('Hello, world!'); 
  // Access the body of the document, then add a paragraph. 
  doc.getBody().appendParagraph('This document was created by Google Apps Script.'); 
  // Get the URL of the document. 
  var url = doc.getUrl(); // Get the email address of the active user - that's you. 
  var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(); 
}
```

Comment: That's because Google Docs (and many other words processor programs) are not integrated development environments that support syntax highlighting. Either write a script to perform syntax formatting (essentially your own JavaScript parser), manually perform the task, live with copy & paste output, or never ever distribute code files within a file, and instead use something suited for the task, like git versioning.

Comment: There is a simpler alternative. Visual Studio supports syntax highlighting and the colors and formatting are copied to the clipboard.  You can take your google script, copypasta into VS, and then copypasta to your destination to achieve (static) syntax highlighting.  May be a better one-off solution than scripting.

Comment: It worked with the Visual Studio Code should I register as Javascript code or other because now as Javascript I don't see well the code it is more light bleu,yellow

Comment: I don't know about Visual Studio Code.  I use VS Pro 2017 which is identical to VS Community 2017 except for licensing for commercial use.  I would get VS2017, create a new .js file copy and paste the code in and then you can change colors via the options to suit your preferred color needs.

Answer (score 1):

As tehhowch said you'll need to write your own javascript code to do syntax formatting and then use the output of that.

You can use this https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_syntax_highlight they already have the script in place you only need to encode your html and put inside `div id="myDiv"` and run the javascript code.

```
<div id="myDiv">
Your encoded html goes here
</div>
```

Example

```
<div id="myDiv">
&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;<br>
&lt;html&gt;<br>
&lt;body&gt;<br>
<br>
&lt;h1&gt;Testing an HTML Syntax Highlighter&lt;/h2&gt;<br>
&lt;p&gt;Hello world!&lt;/p&gt;<br>
&lt;a href="https://www.w3schools.com"&gt;Back to School&lt;/a&gt;<br>
<br>
&lt;/body&gt;<br>
&lt;/html&gt;
</div>
```

Make sure you first encode your html. [< -> &lt, > -> &gt, etc]

Then you can use the output of that . Sample : https://docs.google.com/document/d/1h8oDOZ0ReTgwxnYt2JKflHWJdlianSWWuBgbWcSdJC0/edit?usp=sharing

Reference and further reads : https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_syntax_highlight

Comment: Hello and thank you very much for the answer it's great. I would have some questions because I don't understand how to do it.

Comment: So first I go to the first link and add my code to the left part let's say in the place of &lt;h1&gt;Testing an HTML Syntax Highlighter&lt;/h2&gt; ?After that I am completely lost?where I have to put the div id="myDiv" ?

Comment: Thank you very much but what do you mean encode your html? I have a Code.js file like this function createAndSendDocument() {
  // Create a new Google Doc named 'Hello, world!'
  var doc = DocumentApp.create('Hello, world!');

  // Access the body of the document, then add a paragraph.
  doc.getBody().appendParagraph('This document was created by Google Apps Script.');

  // Get the URL of the document.
  var url = doc.getUrl();

  // Get the email address of the active user - that's you.
  var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

}

Comment: I've edited the post I have 9 lines of code 6 instructions.